# Automapper with Unity - where to put CreateMap stuff?

Tags: c#, unity-container, automapper

I am registering automapper using unity with the following:

```
container
  .RegisterType<AutoMapper.Configuration, AutoMapper.Configuration>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager(),
new InjectionConstructor(typeof (ITypeMapFactory), AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry.AllMappers()))
  .RegisterType<ITypeMapFactory, TypeMapFactory>()
  .RegisterType<IConfiguration, AutoMapper.Configuration>()
  .RegisterType<IConfigurationProvider, AutoMapper.Configuration>()
  .RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>();
```

This works fine but where do I put the equivalent of my Mapper.CreateMap's?

Also, if I have some custom resolvers, how and where do I register these where they have dependencies on other objects I have registered through Unity?

Answer (score 0):

once you've registered everything in IoC, pull the IConfiguration instance from the container to register custom resolvers & create mappings.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @retslig

Not sure I understand what you're asking, but I'm thinking it should look something like...

`IConfiguration configuration = // pull from IoC`
`configuration.CreateMap.....`
`configuratoin.CreateMap.....`
`// whatever else you need`
`configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`

sorry about the formatting, but I can't figure out how to get a block of code in a comment